# mongodb install - requirements?

Tags: mongodb

Anyone know how much disk space and ram a standard ubuntu install on mongo needs? trying to map out my VPS needs ...

Comment: There is no definite answer for this. I can run MongoDB just fine on a 256MB Cloud Server. Then again, it isn't really being stressed. MongoDB also added auto-sharding in 1.6.

Comment: Thanks Rob -- that was actually what i wanted to know. Could a small dev slice support mongo + webserver ...etc

Answer (score 4):

There are no minimum requirements as such, but I wouldn't recomend running Mongo on the same box as your webserver.

> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its cache
>   (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram)

This, along with the reasons mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/660036/131809) (albeit for RDBMS) makes running mongodb on a separate box (even a small one) a much better idea.